# User-Defined Function using BuiltInDocumentProperties stopped automatically updating

Tags: excel, vba

I successfully used the code in in one of your answers to display the Last Saved Date in my excel project.  The code that I used is:

```
Function LastModified() As Date

   LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

It worked like a charm for about a month.  However, since that time, the save date fails to update automatically.  I have to unprotect the sheet, run the macro manually (usually I just select the cell and hit 'ENTER'). I'm not aware of any structure type changes in the excel file that might account for this. Does anyone have any thoughts as to what could be preventing the code from running?

Comment: The code you provided is not related to a `Worksheet_Change` or `Selection_Change` event, which is what it sounds like you are asking about. Are you showing all of the relevant code? Can you show the code that calls this function?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your function Volatile:

```
Function LastModified() As Date
    Application.Volatile
    LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

Comment: Making the function volatile seems to have done it.  It is now updating properly again.  Many thanks!